# SPD 2013 Workflow - Help needed creating folder in subfolder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow

I'm really getting into SharePoint and trying to use it to benefit the business I work for however I've hit my first real roadblock.

**Background:**
I have a list called `Projects` which I create items with the below fields:

- Title
- Site
- PID (determined from a lookup with another list)
- Status.

> eg: Project 1, Site 1, TP-CH-0001, 1. Active Project

I also have another list (document library) called `Project Library` with hierarchy:

1. Active Projects

   - Site 1
   - Site 2
2. Held Projects
3. Closed Projects

**What I want to achieve:**
When a user creates a new item in list `Projects` a SPD WF creates a Folder in the relevant folder in `Project Library`.

> For example:
>   User creates new item in `Projects` with details:
>
> Project 1, Site 1, TP-CH-0001, 1. Active Project

This should create a folder called:

> "TP-CH-001 Project 1"

in the below filepath in `Project Library`

> 1. Active Projects/Site 1/

**Current Settings:**
WF Settings:

```
If CurrentItem:Site equals Site 1
Create item in Project Library (Output to Variable: create3)

Create Item Settings:
Path & Name (*) - 1. Active Projects/Site 1/
Content Type ID - Folder
Title - [%Current Item:PID%] [%Current Item:Title%]
```

The WF now seems to complete the stage but no folder is creating in the specified directory?

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks so much
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `Path & Name (*)` as below

```
1. Active Projects/Site 1/TP-CH-001 Project 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Amal Hashim. 

I managed to use this which created the folder then changed to:
1. Active Projects/Site 1/[%Current Item:PID%] [%Current Item:Title%]
This created it based off the current item info

Thanks so much!