# Errors while Creating a SharePoint Folder while using SharePoint Designer 2013 in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 to modify a site hosted on SharePoint 2016.
I am creating a workflow, and at one step, we need to create a folder in a separate Library that is related to a specific List Item.

I select the Action > Create List Item, and it creates a workflow step "Create item in 'this list'" where I supply that information.

Now I am doing this with workflow variables: (VAR1) for the Library URL itself, and (VAR2) for the Folder's name.

For (1), it is https://dialogue.sppprod/grp/SITE/LIBRARY/ and then for (2), FOLDERNAME

Which then makes the Path and Name [%Variable: VAR1%][%Variable: Var2%]

I get an error: The workflow could not create the list item. Make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to add items to the list.

The list exists. And I have Designer & DesignerPlus permissions.

I have looked at and taken the advice from these sites:
[SPD 2013 Workflow - Help needed creating folder in subfolder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228870/spd-2013-workflow-help-needed-creating-folder-in-subfolder)
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/workflow-to-auto-create-folder-structure-while-creating-new-document-set-in-shar/
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/94621847-cf27-458f-9737-21662c90f9c8/workflow-creating-folder-then-subfolders?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Unfortunately, I am not able to determine what is going on. First off, the workflow doesn't actually stop - it just states that there was an error and does not log any of the logs. And then it actually does other work - such as setting the URL to link to the new folder (though not logging it has done it, and the folder not being made).

What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I don't think you need the full URL of the library - once you select which list to create the new item in (which is really the library), it's going to try to create it in the root folder of that library. You only need the extra stuff in the "Path and name" if you're trying to create a folder as a subfolder somewhere down in a folder hierarchy.  Try making "Path and name" just be the name of the folder you want to create.

Comment: I am going to try right away! Thank you, Dylan! ^.^

Comment: Hi Dylan! That stopped the errors. I have not managed to trigger what I wanted to trigger, but it's no longer breaking. I am going to fix it now, and I think I can, thanks to you! You are amazing. I don't know how to flag your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I added it as a comment since I didn't know for sure if it would work. Since it worked though, I can add it as an actual answer, and then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the full URL of the library - once you select which list to create the new item in (which is really the library), it's going to try to create it in the root folder of that library. You only need the extra stuff in the "Path and name" if you're trying to create a folder as a subfolder somewhere down in a folder hierarchy. Try making "Path and name" just be the name of the folder you want to create.

Comment: I have followed up with the problems I had -- I needed a couple more logs to be able to troubleshoot better. BUT, Dylan, your solution (not repeating the part of the path to get to the Library, since identifying the library is sufficient) worked 100% . Thank you so much! Marked as Solved! You rock!